# Save view states with onSaveInstanceState() in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are many questions which are about onSaveInstanceState() not being called etc. But I was not able to find an answer to this particular problem:

**Initial situation**

A base App created with Android Studio containing the default NavDrawer implementation. Just added a button as test.

**Intention**

Test saving visibility and text of buttons and textviews.

**The Problem**

The values saved with onSaveInstanceState have no effect on the object if orentation changes.

Everything I've tried that was related to a view/object had no effect.

**EDIT**

I think it is because of the way the fragments get "created" -> new instance. How would I pass data to such a "recreated" fragment.

```
 /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private Button btnConnect;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given sectionausgangssituation
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        btnConnect = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conov_btn_connect);
        progress = (ProgressBar) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.conov_progress_connection);

        // StatusLabel.setText(BluetoothController.get().getStatus().getMessage());
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "## test ##",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnConnect.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("savText"));
        } else {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("savText", "Hallo");
    }
```